# Allow intranet web form user to select file on webserver to obtain file path

Tags: php, filesystems, intranet

> Summarized Version:  Is there a way to expose the file directories on
>   my webserver to intranet users of my web form wizard in a file dialog
>   fashion.  This is to allow a webform user to select an existing file
>   located on the webserver's network shares from which I could get that
>   file's complete file path to fill out text input fields on the
>   webform.

I am creating an intranet web based wizard in PHP for my company where users will progress through and fill out various forms.

Some of these forms require the user to enter the [File Name] and [Directory] where a specific file is being stored on one of two network shares (in my specific case these network shares are always mapped to the T: and S: drive letters).

The network share letter (selected by the user in a previous step), serial number (entered by the user in a previous step), [File Name], and [Directory] will be combined to give the full path to the desired file, like so:

[Network Driver Letter]:\[Serial Number]\[Directory]\[File Name]

As an example, let's say the user enters the following data

> [Network Drive Letter] = S:
>
> [Serial Number] = 0012345678
>
> [Directory] = RAID
>
> [File Name] = raidJBOD.bat

The form the user filled out for this example would look like this:

[User Form Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z728D.jpg)

and the full path to the desired file produced by the user's input would be:

> S:\0012345678\RAID\raidJBOD.bat

Note:  I do not want to select the file to upload the file.  This file will be used at a later date, and so instead the file path is stored on a DB so that this file can be accessed at a later time.

This is a cumbersome process and prone to human error when inputting this data.  What I would like to be able to do is to have a link/button on the forms where a file is required that the user can click.  When this link/button is clicked I would like to produce a file dialog box (like the one shown below) that would expose the webserver's network shares (T: and S:) to the user.  From there the user could navigate to the desired file and select it.  All that would be returned would be the file path, from which I could parse into the text input fields on the form.

[File Dialog Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HecJb.jpg)

I am not concerned about the user seeing the network shares' file directories or structure since this is an intranet and all users themselves have access to these directories.

Comment: Of course you can. How would you do that? I would use PHP's built in file-related functions, like "dir", to supply lists of system folders and files.

Comment: Simplest solution is just to list the folders as links that, when clicked, show the next level of folders and files. But if you try a Google search, you might find fancier AJAX-based solutions: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+remote+file+navigation&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS655US656&oq=ajax+remote+file+navigation&aqs=chrome..69i57.9971j0j4&hl=en-US

Comment: @ButtleButkus thanks for the tips.  I will do some research on those fancier solutions, since I would like it to look something like a file explorer/file dialog window if possible.